# JPanels not showing up through else if statements

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jpanel, repaint

Im trying to make a look of a basic with the buttons on the left and then the panels that they are linked to should pop up but im having some issues getting that to work correctly

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MtnDew extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    JButton home, first, faq, contact;
    Image img;
JLabel title, logo, copyright, ntbkImg, firstMsg, ntbkDesc, infoSheets, welcomeMsg;
JLabel basket;
Color blackColor = new Color(10, 10, 10);
Color greenColor = new Color( 10,200,50);
JPanel leftside, top, center, welcome, firstPanel,contactPanel, separator;                                                                                         
Jpanel faqPanel;
public void init ()
{
    setLayout( new BorderLayout());
    doTitle();
    doLeftSide();
    doBottom();
    doCenter();
    setupFAQPanel();
}
public void setupButton( JButton b)
{
    b.setContentAreaFilled( false );
    b.setBorderPainted (false );
    b.setFocusable( false );
    b.setForeground ( blackColor );
    b.addActionListener ( this );
    leftside.add( b );
}
public void doTitle()
{
    title = new JLabel("<HTML>The DewMocracy",JLabel.CENTER);
    img = getImage( getCodeBase(), "MtnDew1.jpeg");
    logo = new JLabel (new ImageIcon( img));
    img = getImage( getCodeBase(), "MtnDew2.jpeg");
    title = new JLabel (new ImageIcon( img));
    top = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
    top.add( logo );
    top.add( title );
    top.setBackground ( blackColor );
    add( top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
public void doLeftSide()
{
    //Links on left bar
    leftside = new JPanel (new GridLayout(5, 1));
    leftside.setBackground(greenColor);
    home = new JButton ("Home");
    first = new JButton ("First DewMocracy");
    faq = new JButton ("FAQ");
    contact = new JButton ("Contact Us");
    setupButton ( home );
    setupButton ( first );
    setupButton ( faq );
    setupButton ( contact );
    basket = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( getImage(   getCodeBase(),"MtnDew3.jpeg")));
    leftside.add(basket);
    add( leftside, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
public void doBottom()
{
    copyright = new JLabel("<HTML>Text from dobottom",JLabel.CENTER);
    copyright.setForeground( blackColor);
    copyright.setOpaque( true);
    copyright.setBackground(greenColor);
    add( copyright, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void doCenter()
{
    center = new JPanel (new BorderLayout());
    center.setBackground( blackColor );
    separator = new JPanel();
    separator.setBackground (greenColor);
    separator.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (10, 20));
    center.add(separator, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    welcome = new JPanel( new FlowLayout());
    welcome.setOpaque(false);
    welcomeMsg = new JLabel("<html><center>"
            + "<H2>this is a welcome message</H2>");
    welcomeMsg.setForeground(greenColor);
    welcome.add(welcomeMsg);
    center.add(welcome,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add( center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public void setupcontactPanel ()
{
    JLabel contactText = new JLabel ( "<HTML><H1>FAQ</H1>"
            + "contact panel test");
    contactPanel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
    contactPanel.setOpaque(false);
    contactPanel.add(contactText);
}
public void setupFAQPanel ()
{
    JLabel faqText = new JLabel ( "<HTML><H1>FAQ</H1>"
            + "lots bla text can go here");
    faqPanel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
    faqPanel.setOpaque(false);
    faqPanel.add(faqText);
}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
{
    JButton src = (JButton)ae.getSource();
    center.removeAll();
    separator = new JPanel ();
    separator.setBackground (greenColor);
    separator.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (10, 20));
    center.add(separator, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    if (src.equals(home))
    {
        center.removeAll();
        center.add(welcome,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    else if (src.equals(contact))
    {
        center.removeAll();
        center.add( contactPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    else if (src.equals(faq))
    {
        center.removeAll();
        center.add( faqPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    else if (src.equals(first))
    {
        center.removeAll();
        center.add( firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    center.repaint();
    validate();
    repaint();
    }

}
```

Ive been trying to get it to work and i even started over doing a simple version but it was not working either. It seems like it is something with my if statement that or im not understanding a key element of the action event

Edit: 
I changed the If statements to what is now in the code and it is still not working. I can click home and FAQ but my other two jbuttons dont seem to work. im trying to test it using the contact button

Comment: I'll hazard a guess and say it's because you're not using '.equals' to evaluate your predicates. '==' only checks the memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contact Us` and `First DewMocracy` buttons do not work as a result of `NullPointerException`. `contactPanel` and `firstPanel` are never initialized and are `null` when you attempt to add them to `center` panel in `actionPerformed()`.

Also, take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). `CardLayout` may be helpful instead of replacing panels manually.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Object src = ae.getSource();
```

to

```
Jbutton src = (JButton)ae.getSource();
```

then

```
if(src.equals(home))
```

or

```
if(src.equals(contact))
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You should add them to the container at the top of your code, when you initialize them, and then under your else if statements use;

```
 contactPanel.setVisible(true);
```

etc. for all of them